# Error building and compiling GCC 5.2.0 from scratch on Vortex86DX

Tags: software-installation, compiling, gcc

In order to upgrade a VortexDX86 custom linux with a `gcc 3.2.3` compiler, I´m trying to built the GCC 5.2.0 compiler to support the latest C++ 11 standard.

I have downloaded its source code from [gcc.gnu.org](http://gcc.gnu.org) and did the standard linux package builder based on the [this GNU link:](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/gcc.html)

```
$ mkdir ../gcc-build
$ cd    ../gcc-build
$ ../gcc-5.2.0/configure --prefix=/usr --disable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-languages=c,c++
```

The configuration runs fine. The I do:

```
$ make
```

And I´m getting the following error:

```
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ftp/pub/gcc-5.2.0/host-i586-pc-linux-gnu/gcc'
g++ -c   -g -DIN_GCC    -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-format -Wmissing-format-attribute -Woverloaded-virtual -fno-common  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DGENERATOR_FILE -I. -Ibuild -I../.././gcc -I../.././gcc/build -I../.././gcc/../include  -I../.././gcc/../libcpp/include  \
    -o build/genmddeps.o ../.././gcc/genmddeps.c
cc1plus: warning: -Wmissing-format-attribute ignored without -Wformat
In file included from ../../gcc/genmddeps.c:19:
../../gcc/system.h:201:19: string: No such file or directory
../../gcc/system.h:218:22: algorithm: No such file or directory
../../gcc/system.h:219:20: cstring: No such file or directory
../../gcc/system.h:220:20: utility: No such file or directory
../../gcc/system.h:249:19: cstdlib: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [build/genmddeps.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ftp/pub/gcc-5.2.0/host-i586-pc-linux-gnu/gcc'
make[2]: *** [all-stage1-gcc] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ftp/pub/gcc-5.2.0'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ftp/pub/gcc-5.2.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

After that the `make` procedure aborts. I´ve installed all the dependencies (`tcl`, `expect`, `dejagnu`, `perl`, `m4`, `gmp`, `mpfr` and `mpc`) and I don´t know what is missing.

As said, the original Vortex linux has a `gcc 3.2.3` compiler version already installed.

I need to solve that but I don´t know where to start from. It seens to have confusion with the own `gcc` libraries....

Help appreciated to solve that.

Comment: Add `--program-suffix=-my-5` to the `../gcc-5.2.0/configure` command....